# Corrupted python package in ubuntu18.04LTS(WSL)

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu

I am a newbie of ubuntu, thanks for reading this thread.

I was trying to remove and reinstall **pip** and **python2.7, python3.6, python3.8** etc...
However I corrupt it somehow,and don't know how to fix it.
Here are some commands I used to remove python :

```
sudo apt-get remove pythonX
sudo apt-get autoremove pythonX
sudo apt-get purge pythonX
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge pythonX
```

X are 2.7 3.6 3.8 etc...

And now I get this error message saying python2.7 is not installed

```
freddie@Freddie:/usr/bin$ sudo apt-get autoremove --purge python2.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'python2.7' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cloud-init : Depends: netplan.io but it is not going to be installed or
                       ifupdown
 dh-python : Depends: python3-distutils but it is not going to be installed
 landscape-common : Depends: python3-gdbm but it is not going to be installed
 python3-commandnotfound : Depends: python3-gdbm but it is not going to be installed
 python3-cryptography : Depends: python3-cffi-backend-api-min (<= 9729)
                        Depends: python3-cffi-backend-api-max (>= 9729)
 python3-pip : Depends: python3-distutils but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: python3-dev (>= 3.2) but it is not going to be installed
 python3-setuptools : Depends: python3-distutils but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true: Success
```

But I still can execute python command like python2.7 --version

```
freddie@Freddie:/usr/bin$ python2.7 --version
Python 2.7.17
```

As suggestion, I tried `sudo apt --fix-broken install` and it give me more errors as below

```
freddie@Freddie:/usr/bin$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apport-symptoms libexpat1-dev libpython3-dev libpython3.6-dev python3.6-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnetplan0 netplan.io python3-cffi-backend python3-distutils python3-gdbm
Suggested packages:
  network-manager | wpasupplicant python3-gdbm-dbg
E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true: Success
E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true: Success
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?
Thanks for your reading.

Answer (score 1):

Command below should remove all python packages and reinstall python3 for ubuntu.

```
sudo apt remove python*
sudo apt install python3 python3-pip
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried `sudo apt remove python*` 
But it still doesn't work.

Comment: This worked for me :) @FreddieLi remember to install python back.

Answer (score 1):

Your snapd is corrupted. Try below steps:

1. Move the config file "/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20snapd.conf" into a backup file(do not delete the file):

   sudo mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20snapd.conf /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20snapd.conf_bkp
2. Now install snapd:

   sudo apt install snapd
3. now move back the "/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20snapd.conf_bkp" to its original name:

   sudo mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20snapd.conf_bkp /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20snapd.conf
4. Your apt should be fixed now, try other installations like python3:

   sudo apt install python3 python3-pip